# Understanding Angular | date filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I'm trying to simply display today's date in an Angular app but it only shows the default no matter what. I get the date with javascript:

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay();
var month = date.getMonth();
var year = date.getFullYear();
var dateNum = Number(day + "" + month + "" + year);
```

So dateNum is 2112016 in the console.

The Angular part:

```
app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.dateInfo = dateNum;

...
```

And the HTML:

```
<body ng-app="weatherApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">

  <div class="row main">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="cardTokyo">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <p class="hour"> Placeholder
              <p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <p class="date"> {{ dateInfo | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}
              <p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->

       ...
```

It just displays 01/01/1970, even if I enter the digits manually instead of dateInfo. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `date` variable instead of `dateInfo` in HTML

Comment: What... `dateInfo` is the name of his variable, that's fine

Comment: It is converted to number, how can a number be rendered with pipes? If It can be done, i haven't seen. Let me know if it can be.

Comment: Just pass a `DateTime` to your View.

Comment: I get the same result using a string.

Comment: Exactly, `date` variable is a Date object and so it will work.

Comment: try: $scope.dateInfo = new Date();

Comment: That did it Nils.

Comment: for angular date filter, please refer to: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to convert it to number and then apply filter. Simply create a date object and apply filter on it with whatever format you want :

**Controller :**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.dateInfo = new Date();
}
```

**In Html :**

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
   <p class="date"> {{ dateInfo | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}</p>
</div>
```